# Method reading file that returns array of class objects

Tags: java, junit

I use JUnit to start main test class that holds `@SuiteClasses` parameter. This parameter holds array of class objects i.e.

```
@SuiteClasses({Test0.class, Test1.class, Test2.class})
```

I want to hold these classes names (Test0, Test1, [..]) in external file (I do not care if it is XML, CSV, TXT etc.) that will hold said names in any manner - doesn't matter if it is separated by comas, new lines or new XML objects. My ideal method should be able to be used like so

```
@SuiteClasses(methodReadingFileAndReturningClassObjs)
```

Is is possible? How can I do that?

Comment: This is not possible in an annotation, which requires a constant expression. You can add an initialization method in the Suite to load the file and add the contained tests.

Comment: May I ask for detailed example how I can pass tests from file to Suite? If I can not put a method in annotation - and I seem to be unable to use variable there - how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: I agree to Raedwald: you shouldnt be doing this.

Comment: I need to do that so I can edit only external file to change of test flow. I.E. I have 10 Tests (Test1-10) and I see that in report Test5 failed I can only execute *that* Test instead of whole process.
This, finished, project will be held in Jar file so it will be huge pain in the ass to recompile it every time a problem occurs if I hardcode test classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the `TestSuite` class I had in mind was a JUnit 3 artifact that doesn't exist in JUnit 4 anymore.

What you can do is extends the `Suite` runner to suit your needs (pun intended).

```
public class FilelistSuite extends Suite {
    public FilelistSuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, loadFromFile(klass));
    }

    private static Class<?>[] loadFromFile(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        // get annotation
        SuiteclassesFile annotation = klass.getAnnotation(SuiteclassesFile.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            throw new InitializationError(String.format("class '%s' must have a SuiteclassesFile annotation", klass.getName()));
        }

       try {
            return fromFile(annotation.filename());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new InitializationError(e.getCause());
        }
    }

    // read file to extract test class names
    private static final Class<?>[] fromFile(String filename) throws RuntimeException {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            return lines
                    .map(FilelistSuite::forName)
                    .toArray(Class[]::new);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
        }
    }

    // wrap Class.forName to be able to use it in the Stream
    private static final Class<?> forName(String line) throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            return Class.forName(line);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    // new annotation for your test suite
    public @interface SuiteclassesFile {
        public String filename();
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to annotate your classes with

```
@RunWith(FilelistSuite.class)
@SuiteclassesFile(filename="/path/to/your/file")
class YourTestClass {}
```

I have not actually tried this, but it should require only minor adjustments.

Actually, since the title of your question is just "Method reading file that returns array of class objects" - the `fromFile` method does that.

Comment: Agreed that this technically answers my question though bear with me for a moment
I tried to run this class. I replaced in my `mainTester` class that is my suite class `@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({TC0.class, TC1.class, TC2.class})` with `@RunWith(FilelistSuite.class)
@SuiteclassesFile(filename="C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\tmp\\testsToRun.csv")`
and my result says "Tests ran:1, Failed: 1" with no errors so I do not know what to fix. I use csv file with following structure:
`tests.TC0 *line break that I can not put here*
tests.TC1...`

Comment: I replaced your `fromFile` method with `readCSV` method that I wrote and know it is working because I am able to start hardcoded suite class with it, though I still get same result

Comment: Added function to question (literally copied from class). Removed fromFile and placed readCSV instead of it. These are only changes I made with you reply so far

Comment: @Uliysess please don't edit questions like this; this makes it an entirely different question. Your original question was "how do I load test classes from file" which I answered; if you can't properly read the file, ask another question. Although I would be surprised if you can't find an existing "how do I read csv files" on SO already.